# Android development architecture

Tags: android, cloud

I want to develop a android app in which the users will post their info about something and that info can be edited by anyone using the app. What kind of knowledge and expertise i would need for this as i'm new to android development.

Comment: EDIT--The knowledge and the technology that would be used for storing the data in above mentioned scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the basic UI creation with **EditText**, **TextView** and **ScrollView**. Then you will need to know **JSON** to send and receive data from the server. You will also need **SQLite** and **SharedPreferences**. You can use **Retrofit** to communicate with the server. Hopefully this is enough. If anything else is required you need to learn it while doing the.

I would suggest you to start off with the app and as you go ahead you will realize what you will require and you can go about learning while you do the app. This is the quickest and according to me the best way to learn.

Comment: I want the data to be stored centrally from where all the users can access and edit it. What type of server will be needed for handling the users request and processing it and reverting them with the data? Could the cloud storage satisfy my needs?

Comment: Yes it will. You will have to upload the entered data when the user chooses to and load the data when the app is opened.

Comment: Can I explicitly post the data to the cloud without the users permission. And do I need the servers for linking my app to the cloud. Please elaborate how can I post all the data to the cloud and retrieve the same when the user logins. Do I need to manage the data myself on the cloud or is it the cloud clouds role. Please suggest some names also of the cloud services which are good at the same and does this in small charges.